# Argument Not Optional error connecting to Access database

Tags: ms-access, vb6, adodb

I have this simple coding for a login form in vb6 with connection to an Access database, but every time I compile this code, it shows an error:

> Argument not optional

and highlights the `Private Sub Loginbtn_Click()` and `txtUsrName`.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
    & "Data Source=E:\Ash\New folder (2)\login form.mdb;" _
    & "Persist Security Info=False"

    conn.Open

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE username = '" & txtUsrName & "'", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        If txtPwd = rs!Password Then

            MsgBox "Username and Password Succesful!"
            'Remove msgbox above then call a form to be load if login is succesful!
            Call MDIForm1.Show
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid Password, try again!", , "Login"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Login, try again!", , "Login"

    End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: is that ` in front of "Private Sub Loginbtn_Click()" from your code, or just a mistake when copying the code in here ?

Comment: is txtUsrName a textbox on your form?

Comment: are you sure you are using VB6 and not VB.Net ?

Comment: changing `, , "Login"` to `, "Login"` can help ? ;).

Comment: @shA.t , ohhh dearr!! you solved my problem!!! i was such a fool, i didnt notice that it has two commas :p thank you so much! and thank you too @Hrqls! :)

Comment: I post it as an answer for finishing the question ;).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need just to change your `MsgBox` commands:

```
MsgBox "Invalid Password, try again!", , "Login"
```

to

```
MsgBox "Invalid Password, try again!", "Login"
```